# Handle click on PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences, android-fragmentactivity

How do you handle click on some preference? This is how my code is:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}


public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.menu_settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the method [onPreferenceTreeClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#onPreferenceTreeClick%28android.preference.PreferenceScreen,%20android.preference.Preference%29) to handle preference click events

The argument Preference is the clicked preference object.